# How to get gender from the user Using Genderize io Api in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to ask one thing suppose I have taken one edit 
    text in that I have entered name (like:Roy) and press 
    submit..
    After I want to know the Roy is Boy or girl using 
    genderize Api..
    Please tell me how to parse that data

Comment: what you have tried so far, please show your code

Comment: No, I am not tried but I want to know the concept and code

Comment: That's not how this site works.  First you try, then we help you.  We aren't a code service.

Answer (score 1):

Using Unirest Lib or make Url req.

Unirest Lib:- [Unirest Lib Android](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java)

Ex. Using Unirest Lib.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> getResponse = Unirest.get("https://api.genderize.io/get")
      .routeParam("method", "get")
      .queryString("name", "Ashvin")
      .asJson();
```